# Differences in the behavior of Tomcat's getRequestURL

Tags: tomcat8, url-scheme, tomcat9, changelog

I found that javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL() behaves differently in 8.5.57 and 8.5.58. If I add a RemoteIpFilter setting to application's web.xml, the 8.5.57 getRequestURL returned https, while 8.5.58 returned http.
The environment is Azure WebApps.

The settings for web.xml are as follows.

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>RemoteIpFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteIpFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>remoteIpHeader</param-name>
            <param-value>x-forwarded-for</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>remoteIpProxiesHeader</param-name>
            <param-value>x-forwarded-by</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>protocolHeader</param-name>
            <param-value>x-forwarded-proto</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RemoteIpFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

The same thing happened between 9.0.37 and 9.0.38.
I couldn't determine which content was affected by the change history, so please let me know.

Best regards.

2021/11/15 Added

I added the following logic to check.

```
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Enumeration e = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = (String)e.nextElement();
            String value = request.getHeader(name);
            out.println(name + " = " + value + "<br>");
        }
```

The Key that the value was set to is as follows.

cache-control, connection, accept, accept-encoding, accept-language, cookie, host, max-forwards, user-agent, sec-ch-ua, sec-ch-ua-mobile, sec-ch-ua-platform, upgrade-insecure-requests, sec-fetch-site, sec-fetch-mode, sec-fetch-user, sec-fetch-dest, x-waws-unencoded-url, client-ip, x-arr-log-id, disguised-host, x-site-deployment-id, was-default-hostname, x-original-url, x-forwarded-for, x-arr-ssl, x-forwarded-proto, x-appservice-proto, x-forwarded-tlsversion

Comment: Are you sure that the IP address of the reverse proxy that forwards the request matches the `internalProxies` parameter (cf. [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_IP_Filter/Initialisation_parameters) for the default value).

Comment: I am using Tomcat in Azure WebApps, and I checked with the logic I added to the question, but it seems that internalProxies is not set. How can I check this?

Comment: What is the remote IP in your access logs? Is it always the same? You didn't set the `internalProxies` parameter in your `web.xml`, so it uses the default value (check the [link given above](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_IP_Filter/Initialisation_parameters)).

Comment: The RemoteIp output in the access.log is always the same and is the IP address of the access source (my home global IP). the Tomcat log is 127.0.0.1, so the same server.
What I want to know is why getRequestURL() behaves differently in different versions, does internalProxies have anything to do with that question?